# How to extract annotations from PDF files?

Tags: command-line, pdf

Is there a command-line tool to extract annotations (comments added using `evince`) from PDF-files?

I search such a solution to send people feedback on their submitted documents. Apart from replying with the annotated PDF as attachment, I want to include a dump of my comments as substitution for a proper changelog in the email's body.

In the `man` pages of tools like `pdftotext`, `pdftohtml` or `pdfinfo` I did not find any helpful options.

Comment: Clarification: I am _not_ talking about _freehand_ (digital ink) comments.

Comment: See the python script in the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf

Comment: @mlberlin thank you for the helpful link! I don't see why I could not find it myself back then – but it has really been a long time ago …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; see

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf

and maybe

https://github.com/measuresforjustice/textricator

(thought we should take this question out of the unanswerd queue)

Comment: is textricator also able to process annotations/comments from PDF documents? The examples and README are only describing processing of "regular" content.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar need and wanted to use python3, so I started developing an extract-pdf-annotations.py with my other tools at https://github.com/foleyj2/teaching-tools
You might find it useful.

Comment: Works well! And thanks for the user-friendly documentation and comments!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/698811/how-to-export-comments-from-a-pdf-file where comments suggest `pdfannotextractor`.